# Advanced Forum - Forum View

Tags: nodes

Hello Advanced Forum Module Experts!

I have installed the plugin and started styling on it and I also took a look on the views were they have listed a couple of views. I looked them up but I don't seem to find the view that display the discusion forums like General Discussion.

The url is /forum/view but I dont seem to find it on views

Where can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General DiScussion - using this view `view-advanced-forum-topic-list`
You can find it here - `/admin/structure/views`
view name - *Advanced Forum topic list*